# Was the modern Santa Claus created by CocaCola?

Tags: history

Is it true that the Coca-Cola company is responsible for the creation of the Modern Santa Claus? e.g. as seen in the attached image

[image]

[Image Source: The Coca-Cola Company Web Site](http://www.thecoca-colacompany.com/heritage/img/cokelore_santa_spriteboy.jpg)

Comment: ...on a related note: http://www.npr.org/2010/12/24/132260025/did-shrooms-send-santa-and-his-reindeer-flying

Comment: quite interesting, I must say

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here is what the [Coca Cola Company says:](http://www.thecoca-colacompany.com/heritage/cokelore_santa.html)

> **It's a common misconception that Santa
> wears a red coat because red is the
> color of Coca-Cola.**
>
> [image: Santa]
>
> In fact, Santa
> appeared in a red coat before artist
> **Haddon Sundblom** painted him for
> Coca-Cola advertising.
>
> The Civil War cartoonist **Thomas Nast**
> drew Santa Claus for *Harper's Weekly*
> in 1862; Santa was shown as a small
> elf-like figure who supported the
> Union.
>
> Nast continued to draw Santa
> for 30 years and along the way changed
> the color of his coat from tan to the
> now traditional red. Though some
> people believe the Coca-Cola Santa
> wears red because that is the Coke®
> color, **the red suit comes from Nast's
> interpretation of St. Nick**.
>
> [image: Thomas Nast's Santa Claus] <sup>**[The Coming of Santa Claus](http://www.allposters.com/-sp/The-Coming-of-Santa-Claus-Posters_i143815_.htm)** by Thomas Nast</sup>

[Snopes](http://www.snopes.com/holidays/christmas/santa/cocacola.asp) also debunks the claim:

> [image: Snopes]
>
> **BUT:**
>
> All this isn't to say that Coca-Cola
> didn't have anything to do with
> cementing the modern image of Santa
> Claus in the public consciousness.
>
> **In an era before the advent of
> television, before color motion
> pictures became common, and before the
> widespread use of color in newspapers,
> Coca-Cola's magazine advertisments,
> billboards, and point-of-sale store
> displays were for many Americans their
> primary exposure to the modern Santa
> Claus image.**

Comment: I, especially like the last paragraph of your answer. Thanks

Comment: Good answer, but a little too USA sided. I'm quite sure, that no or not many Civil War cartoons from Thomas Nast made it to Europe. There the Coca-Cola ads were most likely the only exposure to the red Santa (in Germany actually the similar *Weihnachtsmann*, engl. "Chrismas-Man") and therefore it wouldn't be red in Europe if it wouldn't be for Coca-Cola.

Comment: @Martin - Good point about Europe, especially since Santa Claus is (at least partially) based on the dutch [Sinterklaas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinterklaas). In Austria there have been complaints that the american _Weihnachtsmann_ is replacing the more traditional _[Christkind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christkindl)_.

Comment: For the German speaking readers: [Der Mythos vom Coca-Cola Weihnachtsmann](http://www.markenlexikon.com/coca-cola-weihnachtsmann.html)

Comment: @Oliver_C: Indeed, the Weihnachtsmann vs. Christkind issue is also present in Germany.

Comment: @Martin the red from sinterklaas is because of the church though,  not because of coca cola. tbh, i never see sinterklaas linked to coca cola in belgium